How to replace the obsolete ADClient requestAttributionDetails in iOS app?
I have some old code that uses ADClient.requestAttributionDetails, documented here. The code looks like:
let client = ADClient.shared()
client.requestAttributionDetails { (dict, err) in
    if let dict = dict {
        // sends dictionary to server
    }
}

But that code no longer works. What should the replacement code be? How do you get that dictionary, or something like it, of ad attribution information?

As Apple suggest in their docs, you should call AAAttribution.attributionToken() to generate a token then make API call to their server to retreive attributes
